# Dynamic selection of database, table and SQL query in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, parameter-passing, connection-string

I am new to SSIS project. I try to transfer data to a server which database, table names and SQL query changes according to the year of date.

- Source database: `A17`
- source table: `A_PRICE_17`
- source query:

  ```
   SELECT CODE, PRICE 
   FROM A_PRICE_17 
   JOIN someothertables
  ```

  (so whole table selection is not possible)

Destination:

- Destination database: `B17`
- Destination table:  `B_PRICE_17`

17 comes from year 2017 and next year all database and tables names will be like A18,B18 etc.

I need help on configuring the source & destination, choosing the database, table and query which change related to the years.

I appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Tutoring service requests are off topic as are opinion polls. See [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Make a meta table which holds Year,SourceName,DestinationName and TableName

```
Year | YearAlias | SourceName | DestinationName | TableName
2017 | 17        | A          | B               | Sales
2017 | 17        | A          | B               | Budget
2018 | 18        | A          | B               | Sales
.... | ....      | ..         | ..              | ....
```

Then in SSIS you can loop over each table and make your SQL Selects in a variable with values from SourceName when you use select and values from DestinationName when you want to choose your destination. Then your able to make it dynamic.

Comment: thanks i will try that. any ideas how i can choose the query according to the years ?